# Can I add a column to the Django auth_group table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im a  newbie to Python, I need to add a extra column of data Django's auth_group table ( using Mysql db) . Since it's a built in model, I can't just add a column. Is there a way to extend it?

Answer (score 4):

use *add_to_class* method. Add a new field named *created_at*, in one of you models.py, add this code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
Group.add_to_class('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True))
```